# MaterialUI v5 -> How to style Autocomplete options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply some basic styles to the options inside the Autocomplete component from MUI v5. I'm just trying to change the background color on hover, and based on whether or not it is selected. I've tried 2 approaches based on the documentation, using a theme, and applying the sx prop to Autocomplete.

Using Theme almost has me there, code below:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      styleOverrides: {
        option: {
          '&[aria-selected="true"]': {
            backgroundColor: '#e3abed',
          },

          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#9c27b0',
          },
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I have the ThemeProvider wrapped around my entire app

and the component:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={['1', '2', '3']}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Priority" />}
  onChange={(_e, val) => setPriority(val)}
/>
```

So, this almost works. However the [aria-selected="true"] styling is only being applied when I am also hovering over another option in the dropdown. Otherwise it's the default grey that comes with the component and I don't understand why.

The second path I have tried is to use the sx prop on the Autocomplete component. In the docs it says you can target child components by their class name: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names

Here is my component:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={['1', '2', '3']}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Priority" />}
  onChange={(_e, val) => setPriority(val)}
  sx={{
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-option': {
      backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
    '& .Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  }}
  open
/>
```

That doesn't appear to be having any effect. I've been working on this for almost 2 hours and can't seem to get to the finish line here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
function CustomPaper({ children }) {
  return (
    <Paper 
      sx={{
        "& .MuiAutocomplete-listbox": {
          "& .MuiAutocomplete-option[aria-selected='true']": {
            bgcolor: "purple",
            "&.Mui-focused": {
              bgcolor: "purple",
            }
          }
        },
        "& .MuiAutocomplete-listbox .MuiAutocomplete-option.Mui-focused": {
          bgcolor: "red",
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Following up on Lars' answer, here's an example using a custom Paper component. Just pass in the custom Paper component name to the PaperComponent prop on Autocomplete `<Autocomplete PaperComponent={CustomPaper} {...blahBlahOtherProps} />`. This way is nice if you don't want to override the theme for all Autocomplete components.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem; turns out I just needed to explore the [`Autocomplete` API docs' Props section](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props) a bit further. There are several customization possibilities if you don't want to deal with global theme customization:

1. The `PaperComponent` prop allows customization of *"[t]he component used to render the body of the popup."* Note that simply using `sx` on `Autocomplete` does not work here because (as @bnays-mhz pointed out) the `PopperComponent` that the `PaperComponent` is nested in lives outside the main DOM tree (for z-index/modal UX purposes).
2. The `renderGroup` prop allows overriding the rendering of option group headers.
3. The `renderOption` prop allows overriding the rendering of individual options.

Answer (score 1):

You can override Autocomplete options css by targeting class

'.MuiAutocomplete-popper'

You will have to apply css globally because this node is created outside the root element in DOM.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually able to solve it with theming. It just had to do with getting the right classes into the theme. I spent some time in the inspector to find the right classes on the elements I was styling

Comment: Well, can you post the solution for the rest of us, please @travis_moulton

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue and found a solution.
You Can try this to set the css for options, single option and while hovered (focused) in the Autocomplete using 'sx' prop

> Easy Way to customize your AutoComplete component which can be used in Mui V5

```
  <Autocomplete
  limitTags={1}
  disablePortal
  id="simple-search"
  value={select.region}
  onChange={handleChange("region")}
  options={region}
  sx={{
  width: { sm: "100%", md: 340 },
  "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option": 
      {
        backgroundColor: "#363636",
      },
  "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option[aria-selected='true']":
      {
        backgroundColor: "#4396e6",
      },
  "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option[aria-selected ='true'] .Mui-focused":
      {
        backgroundColor: "#3878b4",
      },
    }}
 disableCloseOnSelect
 multiple
 renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} label="Region" color="info" />
     )}
  />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `disableCloseOnSelect` and `open={true}` should be removed after debugging, but they are very important props to have the ability to see list box options.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style of Autocomplete list items by using the makeStyle() in your functional component with these attributes:

```
'@global': {
    '& .MuiAutocomplete-popper': {
        '& .MuiPaper-root': {
            '& .MuiAutocomplete-listbox': {
                '& li': {
                    fontSize: '14px !important',
                    paddingTop: 0,
                    paddingBottom: 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
  },
```

Because it's being created in the root element of DOM.